# RewriteRule one single node to another domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal, drupal-7

I want to use one node in Drupal 7 as a landingpage with its own domain.

Both domains are linked to the same folder, showing the same content.

**www.domainA.com/landingpage** should be **www.domainB.com** - nothing else ...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainA.com$
RewriteRule ^landingpage http://www.domainB.com [R=301,L]
```

And i want *domainB.com* to show the content of *domainB.com/landingpage*:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainB.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /landingpage [P]
```

This works.

**Now I need to redirect all other pages from domainB back to domainA to avoid Duplicate Content**:
*www.domainB.com/allotherpages* should be *www.domainA.com/allotherpages*

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/landingpage$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainB\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domainA.com [R=301,L]
```

Alltogether it is (part of htaccess-file of Drupal 7):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

RewriteBase /



# HERE STARTS MY CUSTOM RULE-SET:

# Rewrite one node to new Domain:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainA.com$
RewriteRule ^landingpage http://www.domainB.com [R=301,L]

# Front page of domainB shows content of one node:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainB.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /landingpage [P]

# Rewrite all other pages from domainB.com to main domainA.com: 
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/landingpage$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainB\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domainA.com [R=301,L]

# HERE ENDS MY CUSTOM RULE-SET



<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

"Works a little bit" – but breaks the layout and everything – i think, because it rewrites everything else (CSS-files), too ...

Can't find a solution for this.

Edit: 
This seems to work – thanks to *Jon Lin*!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainA\.com$
RewriteRule ^landingpage http://www.domainB.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?www.domainB\.de$
RewriteRule ^$ /landingpage [P]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|svg|ico|jpg)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/landingpage$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?www.domainB\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainA.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't think you need the `P` flag. Since both domains point to the same place, you don't need to proxy the request:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainB.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /landingpage [L]
```

For everything else, you need to capture the request and include that as part of the redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/landingpage$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainB\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainA.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Before, you were redirecting *everything* to the landing page of `www.domainA.com`

If you want to outright prevent css and scripts from being redirected, you can add additional conditions to exclude them:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/landingpage$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainB\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainA.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Tried to change the P-Flag, but it seems to need it. And the RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}, too. Posted the changed Rules above - they seem to work: thank you for your help!